# Выпадающий контент JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Суть такова: При нажатии на Button выезжает контент, при нажатии на другой Button - первый контент скрывается, а второй выезжает - так оно и работает... Но нужно еще... При нажатии на тот же Button (2-й раз) - блок должен скрываться...как осуществить? :)
P.S.
Пробовал с второй кнопкой, у которой был display: none; - при нажатии они менялись, но так выходил очень большой блок и подлагивал JQuery

.

И таких блоков 3-4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(button).one('click', function() {
    $('.news').slideUp('slow');
    $(this).siblings(".news").slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    " Lorem ipsum dolor "
  </div>
  <div class="button ">
    <button type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="bar">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    " Lorem ipsum dolor "
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
    var block=$('.news').css('display');
    if(block=='none') { 
        $('.news').slideUp('slow');
        $(this).siblings('.news').slideToggle('slow');
    }
    else{
        $('.news').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
});
```

Все равно багует... если несколько таких новостей - оно видит только верхние ключи button u news

Comment: О, очередной аккордеон. @Grundy?

Comment: так-то оно так :)

Comment: Но с таким я не сталкивался :( вот и прошу помощи

Comment: можешь разметку какую-нибудь риалистичную добавить и рабочий сниппет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея аккордеона проста: куча панелей которые могут быть открыты, и кнопки которые могут закрывать или открывать панели.

В данном случае для реализации нужно выбрать элемент для которого щелкнули, и открытый элемент (они могут совпадать) и поменять их статус.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.news:visible') // выбираем раскрытую новость
        .add(
          $(this).parent().prev() //берем новость кнопку которой кликнули и добавляем к раскрытым новостям
        ).slideToggle('slow'); //меняем их статус
  });
});
```

```css
.news {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    " Lorem ipsum dolor "
  </div>
  <div class="button ">
    <button type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="bar">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    " Lorem ipsum dolor "
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю!.....

Answer (score 0):

```
var block=$(button).css("block");
if(block=="none")
{
/*открыть*/
}
else
{
/*скрыть*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который использую почти везде где надо что то показать/скрыть:

```
var doc = $(document),
    parent, content;

function beforeShow() {
  $('.sh-parent').removeClass('opened');
}

doc.ready(function(){
  doc.on('click', '.sh-parent .sh-btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent = $('.sh-parent', doc).has($(this)).last();
    content = $('.sh-content', parent);

    /* необязательный фрагмент
    // заморочка со множественной вложеностью - надо открывать только одну
    content = content.filter(function(){
      return !$('.sh-parent', parent).has($(this)).length;
    });
    */

    if (content.css('display') == 'none') {
      beforeShow();
      parent.addClass('opened');
    }
    else {
      parent.removeClass('opened');
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/vu4cj4bq/1/

Имеется кнопка/кнопки .sh-btn, которая открывает/закрывает.

Имеется блок/блоки .sh-content, которые должны открыться/закрыться.

Действие ограничивается контейнером .sh-parent, чтобы открывались/закрывались нужные блоки.

Работает также если имеется вложенность одного контейнера в другой.

Вместо show() и hide() используется css.